# Writing a cumulative thesis in LaTeX - how can I add "front matter" to every chapter/section?

Tags: sectioning, thesis

I am going to write a cumulative thesis (i.e. a thesis consisting of several published academic papers). To make it look nice, I do not want to simply include the PDFs of the papers but rather have a chapter, which is called "Publications". In this chapter, I want to include all papers as individual sections, typeset in a homogeneous style. It is clear, however, that every paper consists of several standardized things:

- Title (should serve as section title and be put to TOC, seems fairly straight-forward)
- List of authors
- Citation information (Title of Publication, Volume, Number, maybe location of conference, pages etc.)
- Year of publication
- Abstract (can simply be set as subsubsection and maybe set in italics or so, so this is also not really part of the problem)

Is there any template or command-based way to set this in a clean LaTeX style? The less copy-and-pasting from other documents is necessary, the better it will be.

Comment: If you have the `.tex` source files, then edit them: (a) Remove preamble; (b) Change `\title{...}` to `\section{...}`; (c) Change `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` to `\subsubsection{Abstract}...`; etc. Then [use `\input{filename}` or `\include{filename}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/164314) in your main document.

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing my PhD thesis I came across this question and I was very sad I have not found any suitable cumulative dissertation template in LaTeX. So I made one. I wish it was so simple as [Ruixi Zhang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/164314/ruixi-zhang) mentioned :) The collisions between packages that handle multiple bibliographies etc. were not nice at all.

I hope it helps someone. You can find it in the [official Overleaf gallery here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cumulative-dissertation-template/rdwdbhmwfyyc). Good luck with your defense.